# Альтернативный текст для icon

Tags: css3, html5, angular2

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Согласно [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#text-equiv-all) весь не текстовый контент должен иметь альтернативный текст. Я понимаю что для `<img>` сужествует атрибут `atl='...'`, но я использую в HTML `<span [ngClass]="link === 'rainbow' ? 'icon-chart' : 'icon-graph-bar'"></span>`, а в CSS соответственно `.icon-graph-bar:before {content: "\EA83";}` и `.icon-graph-bar:before {content: "\E93F";}`. Так вот при добавлении атрибут `atl='...'` к тегу `<span>` компилятор ругается что атрибут `atl='...'` не может быть у тега `<span>`.
Подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: angular не может на такое ругаться, это во-первых, во-вторых тег `alt` есть только у `img`, для других элементов используйте `title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тега span нету атрибута alt , поэтому это и не валидно.
Тег span сам по себе является текстовым элементом, и не нуждается в альтернативном тексте, ваши иконки добавляются через псевдоэлементы  и  в дом дереве как бы не фигурируют, да и к тому же скорее всего сами по себя являются иконочным шрифтом.
Вы конечно можете извратиться и проверять на отображение или подгрузку этих иконок и если они не отображаются выводить соответствующий текст в тегах span или даже сразу его писать а при отображении иконок скрывать его, но на мой вкус это излишне.

UPD

еще можете сделать вот так

```
<span title="альтернативный текст"></span>
```

по крайней мере яндекс считает это допустимым и читает атрибут тайтл как альтернативный текст для блока

Comment: В данном случае это будет являться всплывающей подсказкой, а альтернативный текст появляется когда по какой-то причине не удалось отобразить содержимое (пример- у тега img не удалось загрузить картинку).

Comment: да, этот атрибут в принципе для этого и был придуман, но поисковики считают его дополнительным  к не текстовому контенту.  ну и если совсем строго придерживаться W3C  то нужно делать как я писал в начале,  ивзращаться с проверкой на подгрузку иначе никак. хотя замечу что иконочные шрифты не считаються картинками, скорее спец символами